# Pevent triggering auto save in material ui datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, material-ui, datagrid

I created one `data-grid` and tried to add some records. Add record will create a new empty row. Without filling, I tried to press TAB key, but when focusing on save button, it automatically saved. How can I prevent this behaviour? I need to manually press enter while focusing on save button.

Code below

```
"use client"
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import {
  GridRowsProp,
  GridRowModesModel,
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridEventListener,
  GridRowId,
  GridRowModel,
  GridRowEditStopReasons,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const roles = ['Market', 'Finance', 'Development'];
const initialRows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ash",
    age: 25,
    joinDate: "10-10-2023",
    role: "Market",
  },
];

interface EditToolbarProps {
  setRows: (newRows: (oldRows: GridRowsProp) => GridRowsProp) => void;
  setRowModesModel: (
    newModel: (oldModel: GridRowModesModel) => GridRowModesModel,
  ) => void;
}

function EditToolbar(props: EditToolbarProps) {
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    const id = 10;
    setRows((oldRows) => [...oldRows, { id, name: '', age: '', isNew: true }]);
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'name' },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button color="primary" startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
        Add record
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

export default function FullFeaturedCrudGrid() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = React.useState<GridRowModesModel>({});

  const handleRowEditStop: GridEventListener<'rowEditStop'> = (params, event) => {
    if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
      event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
    }
  };

  const handleEditClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({
      ...rowModesModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
    });

    const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRow!.isNew) {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    }
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: GridRowModel) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    return updatedRow;
  };

  const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel: GridRowModesModel) => {
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 180, editable: true },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age',
      type: 'number',
      width: 80,
      align: 'left',
      headerAlign: 'left',
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'joinDate',
      headerName: 'Join date',
      type: 'string',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'role',
      headerName: 'Department',
      width: 220,
      editable: true,
      type: 'singleSelect',
      valueOptions: ['Market', 'Finance', 'Development'],
    },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Actions',
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: 'actions',
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              sx={{
                color: 'primary.main',
              }}
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon />}
              label="Cancel"
              className="textPrimary"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className="textPrimary"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: 500,
        width: '100%',
        '& .actions': {
          color: 'text.secondary',
        },
        '& .textPrimary': {
          color: 'text.primary',
        },
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        slots={{
          toolbar: EditToolbar,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, there only seems to be a problem with multiple added rows having the same ID `10`, after I used `state` variable `count` to manage the id field, the output looked fine, hope it fixes your issue, please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated if my answer does not help!

```
...
function EditToolbar(props: EditToolbarProps) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(10); // <- changed here
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(() => count + 1); // <- changed here
    setRows((oldRows) => [
      ...oldRows,
      { id: count, name: '', age: '', isNew: true },
    ]);
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,
      [count]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'name' }, // <- changed here
    }));
  };
  ...
```

full code

```
'use client';
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined';
import SaveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Save';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import {
  GridRowsProp,
  GridRowModesModel,
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridEventListener,
  GridRowId,
  GridRowModel,
  GridRowEditStopReasons,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const roles = ['Market', 'Finance', 'Development'];
const initialRows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ash',
    age: 25,
    joinDate: '10-10-2023',
    role: 'Market',
  },
];

interface EditToolbarProps {
  setRows: (newRows: (oldRows: GridRowsProp) => GridRowsProp) => void;
  setRowModesModel: (
    newModel: (oldModel: GridRowModesModel) => GridRowModesModel
  ) => void;
}

function EditToolbar(props: EditToolbarProps) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(10);
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(() => count + 1);
    setRows((oldRows) => [
      ...oldRows,
      { id: count, name: '', age: '', isNew: true },
    ]);
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,
      [count]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: 'name' },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button color="primary" startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
        Add record
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
export default function BasicTable() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = React.useState<GridRowModesModel>(
    {}
  );

  const handleRowEditStop: GridEventListener<'rowEditStop'> = (
    params,
    event
  ) => {
    if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
      event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
    }
  };

  const handleEditClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({
      ...rowModesModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
    });

    const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRow!.isNew) {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    }
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: GridRowModel) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    return updatedRow;
  };

  const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel: GridRowModesModel) => {
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 180, editable: true },
    {
      field: 'age',
      headerName: 'Age',
      type: 'number',
      width: 80,
      align: 'left',
      headerAlign: 'left',
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'joinDate',
      headerName: 'Join date',
      type: 'string',
      width: 180,
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      field: 'role',
      headerName: 'Department',
      width: 220,
      editable: true,
      type: 'singleSelect',
      valueOptions: ['Market', 'Finance', 'Development'],
    },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      type: 'actions',
      headerName: 'Actions',
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: 'actions',
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              sx={{
                color: 'primary.main',
              }}
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon tabIndex={0} />}
              label="Cancel"
              className="textPrimary"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            tabIndex={0}
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className="textPrimary"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            tabIndex={0}
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: 500,
        width: '100%',
        '& .actions': {
          color: 'text.secondary',
        },
        '& .textPrimary': {
          color: 'text.primary',
        },
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        slots={{
          toolbar: EditToolbar,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wylkj3?file=Demo.tsx)

Comment: It's not working in my system. Let me try to change the versions

Comment: Hy, it's worked. I used 6.2.1. Updated it to 6.19.1 and works fine.